# How to call rpc service method from another rpc service?

Tags: gwt, rpc, gwt-rpc

There is two different GWT-RPC services.

1. `TaxService` which contains method `TaxDto getTax(ProductDto product);`
2. `ProductService` which contains method `Double getTotalWithTax(ProductDto product);

I want to call `getTax()` method from `getTotalWithTax()` how can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

To call `getTax()` on the server side, create an instance of `TaxServiceImp` that is accessible to `getTotalWithTax(ProductDto product)`;  Call the method from there.

```
    public class ProductService Impl extends XsrfProtectedServiceServlet{

         TaxServiceImp taxServImpInstance = new TaxServiceImp();

         Double getTotalWithTax(ProductDto product){

             TaxDto taxDtoInstance = taxServImpInstance.getTax();
             //process your data and return what you need

             return myDouble;

         }

    }
```